# Binary editing in java

Tags: java, file, byte

I have a file that I am trying to binary edit to cut off a header.

I have identified the start address of the actual data I want to keep in the file, however I am trying to find a way in Java where I can specify a range of bytes to delete from a file.

At the moment I am reading the file in a (Buffered)FileInputStream, and the only way I can see to cut off the header of this file is to save from my start address to the end of the file in memory, then write that out overwriting the original file.

Is there any functionality to remove bits in files without having to go through the process of creating a whole new file?

Comment: If you're on Unix or Linux you can use `tail -c+NNN` where _NNN_ is the offset in the file at which to start copying (i.e. skip bytes 0 thru NNN-1.

Comment: I don't think so, AFAIK it is not even possible in the underlying OS API.  You could use `RandomAccessFile` to overwrite the beginning of the file, but that is probably more hassle than it's worth.  Just write it to a new file.

Comment: This is a function of a program I am building so unix commands won't work too well. I had a look at RandomAccessFile as well as FileChannel, SeekableByteChannel but they all seem to hard truncate the file to a given size, and that's about as far as you can go

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to truncate the file ([setLength](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength%28long%29)) but there is not API to remove an arbitrary sequence from inside.

If the file is so large that there is a performance issue to rewrite it, I suggest to split it into several files. Some performance maybe can be gained by using RandomAccessFile to seek to the point of deletion, rewrite from there and then truncate.

Comment: I saw that method too but it looks like if I wanted to remove a footer then it would be cool. I ended up re-writing to a temp file using transferTo() in the FileChannel class. I have posted my snippet below

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it uses a RandomAccessFile to wipe out the un-needed parts of the file, by first seeking to the start index, then wiping the un-needed characters onwards.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int startIndex = 21;
        int numberOfCharsToRemove = 20;

        // Using a RandomAccessFile, overwirte the part you want to wipe
        // out using the NUL character
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(new File("/Users/waleedmadanat/Desktop/sample.txt"), "rw")) {
            raf.seek(startIndex);

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCharsToRemove; i++) {
                raf.write('\u0000');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what Antix wanted. The length of the file is the same. There are only \0 characters in the file instead of the original characters. I think Antix wanted the characters to be removed from the file. After the operation the File should be numberOfCharsToRemove shorter.

Comment: I needed to actually remove the bits from the file, so this would be okay for nulling out the data but it would still have a massive header of 0's before the actual data. Edit: Beaten :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any API method to perform what I wanted (goes with the answers above)

I solved it by just re-writing the file back out to a new file, then replacing the old one with the new one.

I used the following code to perform the replacement:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");
FileChannel chanOut = fout.getChannel();
FileChannel chanIn = fin.getChannel();

chanIn.transferTo(pos, chanIn.size(), chanOut);
```

Where pos is my start address to begin the file transfer, which occurs directly under the header that I am cutting out of this file.

I have also noticed no slowdowns using this method